# Why dosnt this SQL statement work?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM  conference_attende_options
INNER JOIN conference_options ON conference_attende_options.option_id = conference_options.option_id
WHERE conference_attende_options.PersonID = '4767'
AND option_type = 'guest_field_trip' OR option_type = 'guest_trans_meal'
ORDER BY conference_options.option_id ASC;
```

It returns all the records with the 'option_type''s of 'guest_field_trip' and 'guest_trans_meal'... it suppose to only return records that match the 'PersonID'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use brackets like so:

```
AND (option_type = 'guest_field_trip' OR option_type = 'guest_trans_meal')
```

Comment: In that case I suggest you click on the "Accept answer" button (or whatever they named it - I haven't posted a question for quite some time :-)

Comment: I will soon as it lets me.. 3 more mins!

Comment: There's a time limit? Well, I could probably look it up on meta why there is one, but thanks anyway ;-)